# sed command to grep a specific value

Tags: linux, unix, sed

I have a log file that has the following lines;

```
Time = 0.9998

DILUBiCGStab:  Solving for Ux, Initial residual = 1.99533113036e-06, Final residual = 2.96249561335e-10, No Iterations 1
DILUBiCGStab:  Solving for Uy, Initial residual = 0.000417321531609, Final residual = 7.45521650555e-10, No Iterations 2
DILUBiCGStab:  Solving for Uz, Initial residual = 0.000101783532684, Final residual = 2.22925230463e-10, No Iterations 2
PISO corrector = 1
GAMG:  Solving for p, Initial residual = 0.0176383087802, Final residual = 0.000128354492605, No Iterations 2
GAMG:  Solving for p, Initial residual = 0.00157044214071, Final residual = 6.05258709305e-06, No Iterations 3
time step continuity errors : sum local = 1.07897616229e-11, global = -1.21038993529e-13, cumulative = 3.09373543327e-11
PISO corrector = 2
GAMG:  Solving for p, Initial residual = 0.00396386732982, Final residual = 1.39668381997e-05, No Iterations 2
GAMG:  Solving for p, Initial residual = 0.000387895480416, Final residual = 2.61276578576e-06, No Iterations 2
time step continuity errors : sum local = 4.66055831479e-12, global = -9.01547272112e-14, cumulative = 3.08471996055e-11
PISO corrector = 3
GAMG:  Solving for p, Initial residual = 0.0014865117999, Final residual = 5.92873264058e-06, No Iterations 2
PISO: converged in 3 correctors
GAMG:  Solving for p, Initial residual = 0.00018575923819, Final residual = 1.19602052482e-06, No Iterations 2
time step continuity errors : sum local = 2.13399696121e-12, global = -5.81036463017e-14, cumulative = 3.07890959592e-11
DILUBiCGStab:  Solving for nuTilda, Initial residual = 1.76763063985e-06, Final residual = 1.29954103535e-10, No Iterations 1
ExecutionTime = 22441.72 s  ClockTime = 22620 s
deltaT
Courant Number mean: 0.819402719286 max: 27.6501988889

FunctionObject:cflBlendingFactor:blendingFactors_regAir_1
60 faces with Courant number based blending for field U
U maximum, minimum and mean blending factors: 1, 0, 0.99151536773

Time = 1

DILUBiCGStab:  Solving for Ux, Initial residual = 1.99417672249e-06, Final residual = 2.96731829464e-10, No Iterations 1
DILUBiCGStab:  Solving for Uy, Initial residual = 0.000410917566734, Final residual = 7.49859275563e-10, No Iterations 2
DILUBiCGStab:  Solving for Uz, Initial residual = 0.000102377986855, Final residual = 2.29772350504e-10, No Iterations 2
PISO corrector = 1
GAMG:  Solving for p, Initial residual = 0.0176826205863, Final residual = 0.000128293418219, No Iterations 2
GAMG:  Solving for p, Initial residual = 0.0015679277464, Final residual = 5.63358605766e-06, No Iterations 3
time step continuity errors : sum local = 1.00341782615e-11, global = -1.18362574514e-13, cumulative = 3.06707333847e-11
PISO corrector = 2
GAMG:  Solving for p, Initial residual = 0.00396565210757, Final residual = 1.3750596194e-05, No Iterations 2
GAMG:  Solving for p, Initial residual = 0.000389224800858, Final residual = 2.48748848039e-06, No Iterations 2
time step continuity errors : sum local = 4.43399728322e-12, global = -9.30058928658e-14, cumulative = 3.05777274918e-11
PISO corrector = 3
GAMG:  Solving for p, Initial residual = 0.00148579017778, Final residual = 5.81035754297e-06, No Iterations 2
PISO: converged in 3 correctors
GAMG:  Solving for p, Initial residual = 0.000185729750804, Final residual = 1.1427315649e-06, No Iterations 2
time step continuity errors : sum local = 2.03756129196e-12, global = -6.12459431033e-14, cumulative = 3.05164815487e-11
DILUBiCGStab:  Solving for nuTilda, Initial residual = 1.76831276642e-06, Final residual = 1.28999442413e-10, No Iterations 1
ExecutionTime = 22451 s  ClockTime = 22630 s
```

So, all I need is to be able to read the values 0.0176383087802 and 0.0176826205863 only and only. My attempt is as below;

```
cat log | grep 'Solving for p' | cut -d' ' -f9 | sed -n 'p;N' | tr -d ',' > p_tmp.dat
```

However, this always leads to read all values. I have kept reading about the sed command but I don't seem to get around for whatever reason. Anyone can provide some insight on how to make it read the first value of each time, and outputted to the dat file.

Comment: Could you please do lemme know if my solution helped you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why are you emphasizing on `sed` command to do some task that can be easily achieved by other commands. sed is mainly used for find and replace, but seems you want to achieve something else.

in case if you meant to fetch the first record value you can use below approach.

```
 [cloudera@quickstart sub1]$ cat a.txt 
    Time = 0.9998

DILUBiCGStab:  Solving for Ux, Initial residual = 1.99533113036e-06, Final residual = 2.96249561335e-10, No Iterations 1
DILUBiCGStab:  Solving for Uy, Initial residual = 0.000417321531609, Final residual = 7.45521650555e-10, No Iterations 2
DILUBiCGStab:  Solving for Uz, Initial residual = 0.000101783532684, Final residual = 2.22925230463e-10, No Iterations 2
PISO corrector = 1
GAMG:  Solving for p, Initial residual = 0.0176383087802, Final residual = 0.000128354492605, No Iterations 2
GAMG:  Solving for p, Initial residual = 0.00157044214071, Final residual = 6.05258709305e-06, No Iterations 3
time step continuity errors : sum local = 1.07897616229e-11, global = -1.21038993529e-13, cumulative = 3.09373543327e-11
PISO corrector = 2
GAMG:  Solving for p, Initial residual = 0.00396386732982, Final residual = 1.39668381997e-05, No Iterations 2
GAMG:  Solving for p, Initial residual = 0.000387895480416, Final residual = 2.61276578576e-06, No Iterations 2
time step continuity errors : sum local = 4.66055831479e-12, global = -9.01547272112e-14, cumulative = 3.08471996055e-11
PISO corrector = 3
GAMG:  Solving for p, Initial residual = 0.0014865117999, Final residual = 5.92873264058e-06, No Iterations 2
PISO: converged in 3 correctors
GAMG:  Solving for p, Initial residual = 0.00018575923819, Final residual = 1.19602052482e-06, No Iterations 2
time step continuity errors : sum local = 2.13399696121e-12, global = -5.81036463017e-14, cumulative = 3.07890959592e-11
DILUBiCGStab:  Solving for nuTilda, Initial residual = 1.76763063985e-06, Final residual = 1.29954103535e-10, No Iterations 1
ExecutionTime = 22441.72 s  ClockTime = 22620 s
deltaT
Courant Number mean: 0.819402719286 max: 27.6501988889

FunctionObject:cflBlendingFactor:blendingFactors_regAir_1
60 faces with Courant number based blending for field U
U maximum, minimum and mean blending factors: 1, 0, 0.99151536773

Time = 1

DILUBiCGStab:  Solving for Ux, Initial residual = 1.99417672249e-06, Final residual = 2.96731829464e-10, No Iterations 1
DILUBiCGStab:  Solving for Uy, Initial residual = 0.000410917566734, Final residual = 7.49859275563e-10, No Iterations 2
DILUBiCGStab:  Solving for Uz, Initial residual = 0.000102377986855, Final residual = 2.29772350504e-10, No Iterations 2
PISO corrector = 1
GAMG:  Solving for p, Initial residual = 0.0176826205863, Final residual = 0.000128293418219, No Iterations 2
GAMG:  Solving for p, Initial residual = 0.0015679277464, Final residual = 5.63358605766e-06, No Iterations 3
time step continuity errors : sum local = 1.00341782615e-11, global = -1.18362574514e-13, cumulative = 3.06707333847e-11
PISO corrector = 2
GAMG:  Solving for p, Initial residual = 0.00396565210757, Final residual = 1.3750596194e-05, No Iterations 2
GAMG:  Solving for p, Initial residual = 0.000389224800858, Final residual = 2.48748848039e-06, No Iterations 2
time step continuity errors : sum local = 4.43399728322e-12, global = -9.30058928658e-14, cumulative = 3.05777274918e-11
PISO corrector = 3
GAMG:  Solving for p, Initial residual = 0.00148579017778, Final residual = 5.81035754297e-06, No Iterations 2
PISO: converged in 3 correctors
GAMG:  Solving for p, Initial residual = 0.000185729750804, Final residual = 1.1427315649e-06, No Iterations 2
time step continuity errors : sum local = 2.03756129196e-12, global = -6.12459431033e-14, cumulative = 3.05164815487e-11
DILUBiCGStab:  Solving for nuTilda, Initial residual = 1.76831276642e-06, Final residual = 1.28999442413e-10, No Iterations 1
ExecutionTime = 22451 s  ClockTime = 22630 s


[cloudera@quickstart sub1]$ cat a.txt | sed -n '/PISO corrector = 1/{n;P;}' | cut -d' ' -f9 | tr -d ','
0.0176383087802
0.0176826205863
```

Comment: So, the PISO correct =1 and 2 and 3 are outputted at different times. So, I need to grep the first value of the initial residual for the PISO corrector = 1 for each time. What I provided just part of one line of the whole time. The sed commnad is essential here as I want to be able to read it for all times and save it in one arrat. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Hi I have updated the answer please refer the updated command now . I think this is what you need

Comment: if needed you can modify the pattern  in sed according to your requirement,but it should work if you want to fetch corrector = 1 at different intervals

Comment: Many thanks for your time again! I have just edited my post to make more clear to you. So, I need to only pick the values 0.0176383087802 and 0.0176826205863 at both times!

Comment: If I use cat log | grep 'Solving for p' | cut -d' ' -f9 | sed -n 'p;N' | tr -d ',' > p_tmp.dat

Comment: It will pick 0.0176383087802
0.00157044214071
0.00396386732982
0.000387895480416
0.0014865117999
0.00018575923819
0.0176826205863
0.0015679277464
0.00396565210757
0.000389224800858
0.00148579017778
0.000185729750804

Comment: So, all I want to use the same cat command to pick only 0.0176383087802 and 0.0176826205863 from each time!

Comment: @Strick, your snipped code is outputting all values i.e. 0.0176826205863
0.00396565210757
0.00148579017778
0.000185729750804

Comment: I want it to output 0.0176826205863 instead

Comment: @TariqKhamlaj, my command doesn't output all values it should is giving only required one, please do post coming output under my answer and we could talk on this one then.

Comment: Can u try changing sed part in my command to sed :PISO corrector = 1:{n;P;}

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I want to keep it with command cat if possible!

Comment: Basically in my command i am tryng to get the next line after the pattern thus i have taking "PISO corrector = 1" as a pattern can you just tweak the pattern in my sed command  and try give it run

Comment: @TariqKhamlaj, only cat command will not be capable of doing this, you definetly need other tools for same lemme know if my solution worked for you.

Comment: @TariqKhamlaj, and if you want to cat your file first and then use commands that is called UUOC(useless use of cat) command, since awk or sed can read files by themselves so you don't need cat in it.

Comment: @TariqKhamlaj : my command is working completely fine. I have tried executed it. My bad that previously i updated my command in answer but forgot to update the output. If you had tried it. It should have worked. Please give a try and let me know if it is working for you also

Comment: @ Strick, many thanks! It finally worked! So, happy with your solution!

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Can you please alsi upvote the answer ?

Comment: @ Strik, quick question, how to grep also the time and have it as a column too. e.g. 0.9998 1 0.0176383087802
0.0176826205863. In one command!

Comment: Not sure how we can achieve this in a single statement. But awk may be helpful in such scenerio.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you need to read very first value of a found string's line. Could you please try following then.

```
awk '/Solving for p/ && match($0,/=[^,]*/) && ++count==1{print substr($0,RSTART+2,RLENGTH-2)}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:***

```
awk '                                                        ##Starting awk program from here.
/Solving for p/ && match($0,/=[^,]*/) && ++count==1{         ##Checking condition if a line has string Solving for p and then matching a regex to match everything from first occurrence of = till first occurrence of , THEN checking condition if variable count value is equal to 1 then do following.
  print substr($0,RSTART+2,RLENGTH-2)                        ##Printing sub-string of line starting from RSTART+1 value to till valie of RLENGTH-2 value.
}
'  Input_file                                                ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, if I understand what you want to achieve.
In the case you want to extract the very first match only.

```
cat log | grep 'Solving for p' | head -1 | cut -d' ' -f9 | tr -d ','
```

No need to use sed at all

Comment: What if we have those lines at different times? Those lines that I snipped are just at a specific time and are part of a residual. So, again, I need to read the first value of the initial pressure at the PISO corrector = 1 and save them into a dat file. You command is valid only for the current case but if I read the entire log file at different times, it won't work! Thanks again for the hep\